# How to create Semi-transparent buttons

Tags: ios, image, button

If anyone could show me how to make a button similar to the one in the image below I would be really grateful!! I intend to use the button in XCode for Iphone/ IPad

[image: button]

Comment: For a semi-transparent (translucent) button, set the `opacity` property to something like `0.7`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of this, but did you tried to make a e.g. 50% transparent (.GIF / .BMP) picture and set it as a background of the button?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I solved this now, I set the alpha of my image to 0.7 with the following code

```
shootButton.alpha = 0.7;
```

And I also used  photoshop's "Satin" effect to give it a more translucent effect.